# Two-dimensional Perron formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

There is a well-known Perron formula, which connects a mean value of certain arithmetic function with its Dirichlet series:
$$ \sum_{n\le x} f(n) = {1\over 2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(s) x^s s^{-1} ds, $$
where $F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) n^{-s}$, $c>\sigma_f$, $F(s)$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re s > \sigma_f$.

Is there any two-dimensional analog? Something of form 
$$ \sum_{m,n\le x} f(m,n) = {1\over 2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(z,w) x^{z+w} (zw)^{-1} dz dw $$
for $F(z,w) = \sum_{m,n=1}^\infty f(m,n) m^{-z} n^{-w}$.

Comment: From the one-dimensional version you can easily deduce the two-dimensional version. In particular, your second display is valid for $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$ except that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ should be squared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really more of a comment, but I don't have the ability to comment.
The error term in the truncated two-dimensional Perron formula has been worked out in pain-staking details in the following paper of Balazard, et. al

http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~balazard/pdfdjvu/19.pdf

See Proposition 5 and 6.

Of course, you probably should work with a smoothing, in which case these issues disappear. Without a smoothing the convergence issues in the two-dimensional Perron integral could get rather annoying.